# Quicksort not sorting input [-1, 2, -8, -10]

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

Here is the code:

```
public int[] sortArray(int[] arr) {
    // sort array using quicksort
    sort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    return arr;
}

private void sort(int[] arr, int low, int high) {
    int pi = partition(arr, low, high);

    if (low < pi - 1) { // sort left half
        sort(arr, low, pi - 1);
    }
    if (pi < high) { // sort right half
        sort(arr, pi, high);
    }
}

// partitiion an array by selecting a pivot 
private int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    // get random index as the pivot
    int pivot = (left + right) / 2;

    while (left <= right) {
        while (arr[left] < arr[pivot]) {
            left++; // increment left index if left index is less than the pivot 
        }
        while (arr[right] > arr[pivot]) {
            right--; // decrement right index if right index is greater than the pivot 
        }
        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr, left, right); // elements into using pivot 
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    return left;
}

private void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

For some reason, this quicksort code does not sort the array.

Given the input: `[-1, 2, -8, -10]`, the output is this: `[-10, -1, -8, 2]`.

Here is a link to the problem on Leetcode (912. Sort an Array): https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-an-array/

The pivot is always within the bounds and I can't see anything wrong with the rest of the code either.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is perfectly correct! You just have to replace this line:

```
 int pivot = (left + right) / 2;
```

with:

```
int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
```

and then update your comparisons accordingly:

- replace `arr[left] < arr[pivot]` with `arr[left] < pivot`,
- replace `arr[right] > arr[pivot]` with `arr[right] > pivot`.

Comment: The bug in OP's code occurred whenever `left == pivot` or `right == pivot`. In such a situation the pivot value was swapped with the value at index `right` or `left` and the next iteration of the loop compared against a different pivot value!

Answer (score 0):

You `partition` method should probably look like this (must admit I didn't write quicksort for a very very long time)

```
 // partitiion an array by selecting a pivot
private static int partition(int[] arr, int left, int right) {
    // get random index as the pivot
    int pivot = (left + right) / 2;
    while (left <= right) {
        while (arr[left] < arr[pivot]) {
            left++; // increment left index if left index is less than the pivot
        }
        while (arr[right] > arr[pivot]) {
            right--; // decrement right index if right index is greater than the pivot
        }
        if (left < right) {
            swap(arr, left, right); // elements into using pivot
        }
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    return left;
}
```

Comment: If you changes the input array, your solution fails.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Our experience says that code-only answers are not very useful. Could you please add an explanation what you’ve changed in the method and how it solves the issue? Thanks.